# summarizing data frame in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, summary

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['y',NaN,'y',NaN,NaN,'x','x','y',NaN],'b':[NaN,'x',NaN,'y','x',NaN,NaN,NaN,'y'],'d':[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0]})
```

I'm trying to summarize this dataframe using `sum`. I thought `df.groupby(['a','b']).aggregate(sum)` would work but it returns an empty `Series`.

How can I achieve this result?

```
   a  b
x  1  1
y  2  1
```

Comment: @unutbu: Sorry, you're right, the second row should be y 2 1. I've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
NaN = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a':['y',NaN,'y',NaN,NaN,'x','x','y',NaN],
     'b':[NaN,'x',NaN,'y','x',NaN,NaN,NaN,'y'],
     'd':[32,12,55,98,23,11,9,91,3]})

melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['d'], value_vars=['a', 'b'])
result = pd.pivot_table(melted, values='d', index=['value'], columns=['variable'], 
                        aggfunc=np.median)
print(result)
```

yields

```
variable     a     b
value               
x         10.0  17.5
y         55.0  50.5
```

---

**Explanation**:

[Melting the DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) with `melted = pd.melt(df, value_vars=['a', 'b'])` produces

```
     d variable value
0   32        a     y
1   12        a   NaN
2   55        a     y
3   98        a   NaN
4   23        a   NaN
5   11        a     x
6    9        a     x
7   91        a     y
8    3        a   NaN
9   32        b   NaN
10  12        b     x
11  55        b   NaN
12  98        b     y
13  23        b     x
14  11        b   NaN
15   9        b   NaN
16  91        b   NaN
17   3        b     y
```

and now we can use [`pd.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) to pivot and aggregate the `d` values:

```
result = pd.pivot_table(melted, values='d', index=['value'], columns=['variable'], 
                        aggfunc=np.median)
```

Note that the `aggfunc` can take a list of functions, such as `[np.sum, np.median, np.min, np.max, np.std]` if you wish to summarize the data in more than one way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but is there a way to make this a bit more flexible? For example if I had 'd':[32,12,55,98,23,11,9,91,3] and wanted to calculate medians instead of sums it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes -- instead of  `pd.crosstab` (which creates a frequency table), use `pd.pivot_table` with your choice of `aggfunc`.

Comment: Perfect, it works great!! Thanks a lot for your help and great explanation!